# Absolute position in Image

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there anyone who can solve that kind of problem ? I have a background image and I need components at the same place in that image when I change the resolution, the component remains in the same point according to the view but not acording to the image. That I have the problem with responsivity.

There are some pictures for an example: Look at the point "sentence".

[image]

[image]

And there is xaml code:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid >
            <Image Source="Path" Stretch="Fill"/>
            <Canvas>

                <Ellipse Fill="White" Height="15" Width="15" Canvas.Left="170" Canvas.Top="103" />
                <TextBlock Text="Sentence" Foreground="Green" 
                           Width="150" Height="Auto" Canvas.Left="28" Canvas.Top="122" 
                           TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" TextAlignment="Right"/>
             </Canvas>
        </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: you should directly state what your question is so no one has to guess

Comment: Probably set `Stretch="None"` on the Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will need to calculate the position in the code behind, and reset the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` property, for example like this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" SizeChanged="canvas_SizeChanged">
            <Canvas.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/111.png" />
            </Canvas.Background>
            <Ellipse x:Name="elps" Fill="White" Height="15" Width="15" Canvas.Left="170" Canvas.Top="103" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="tb" Text="Sentence" Foreground="Green"
                   Width="150" Height="Auto" Canvas.Left="28" Canvas.Top="122"
                   TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" TextAlignment="Right" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

code behind:

```
private double width;
private double height;

private void canvas_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (width == 0 || height == 0)
    {
        width = canvas.ActualWidth;
        height = canvas.ActualHeight;
    }
    else
    {
        var newwidth = canvas.ActualWidth;
        var newheight = canvas.ActualHeight;
        elps.Width = 15 * (newwidth / width);
        elps.Height = 15 * (newheight / height);
        Canvas.SetTop(elps, 103 * (newheight / height));
        Canvas.SetLeft(elps, 170 * (newwidth / width));
        Canvas.SetTop(tb, 122 * (newheight / height));
        Canvas.SetLeft(tb, 28 * (newwidth / width));
    }
}
```

I personally think it's better to put your `Ellipse` and `TextBlock` in one control and move together, and this calculation is just a sample, you can calculate it by yourself.

Comment: Thanks you. I found that it is better to use viewBox.